# Python and selenium: choose option from dropdown in table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am still new to Python and Selenium. I would like to choose a certain option from a dropdown that is contained in an html table. However I can not get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated?

Snippet of HTML-Code:

```
<table class="StdTableAutoCollapse">
<tr>
<td class="StdTableTD150">
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_LbLProd1" class="StdLabel150">Prod1:</span>
</td>
<td class="StdTableTD330">
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceBody$DropDownListUnitType"            onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceBody$DropDownListUnitType\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_DropDownListUnitType" class="StdDropDownList330" Class="option">
    <option selected="selected" value="#">- nothing -</option>
    <option value="P">Dummy1</option>

</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
```

I tried the following to select the value "Dummy1"

Python Code:

```
dropdown1 =     
browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_DropDownListUnitType')
select = Select(dropdown1)
select.select_by_value("P")
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I get an error on the IPython console in Anaconda with Python 3.6:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
[id="ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_DropDownListUnitType"]
```

**EDIT2**

I checked whether the problem is due to different iframes as mentioned by comments and in other questions here on stackoverflow. I used the idea mentioned in this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes to check for iframes and tried with the example of Alibabas login page. There two different iframes where shown. In the page I am trying to use with selenium there is only one iframe.

Comment: Did you get any exceptions? Share logs

Comment: Yes, I do get an exception, please see the EDIT above. I guess it tells me that there is no such element in the page I am opening, which is something I do not understand. I am still fairly new, any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Code looks fine. Is the page really loaded?

Comment: Yes, the page is completely loaded, I have also put some time.sleep(30) before the code I provided to make sure the page is completely loaded. Unfortunately I cannot share the page or a link to a it, it is internal.

Comment: Check whether your table located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Hello Andersson, there are no strings "iframe" in the source code of the page. Might it still be there that there is an iframe?

Comment: Yes. `iframe` is not a part of main page `HTML` source code. You need to use `HTML` code inspector, like `Firebug`, to check `iframe` presence

Comment: I checked, there is only one iframe according to firefox, please do also see my EDIT2. Do you have any other ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, Webdriver is having difficulty in directly reaching to the drop down using its **id**. You may need to first locate the table and then reach to the drop down. Try following and let me know, whether it works.

```
 dropdown1 =     
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='StdTableAutoCollapse']/tr[1]/descendant::select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_DropDownListUnitType'][1]")
 select = Select(dropdown1)
 select.select_by_value("P")
```

Comment: Hello Mahipal, thank you. I tried and do not get an error, however, the code you proposed selects another dropdown in the table, the third dropdown. I am 100% sure though the id and name above contains the first dropdown of the table. Also, I guess I should change your code to
     `browser.find_element_by_xpath`

right? I took out the "driver"

Comment: Sorry Rashid, it was a typo. Yes, you should change the code to `browser.find_element_by_xpath`. I have modified my answer to select the first drop down. Could you try that and let me know, whether it works?

Comment: Hello Mahipal, thanks for answering again. I tried the code, it somehow selects the dropdown in the third row instead of the dropdown in the first row. This is weird because the third is in a different row `<tr>`with a different ID: `<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceBody_DropDownListGroup3...` Do you have any other ideas? I am really desperate to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the xpath in my answer. It should select the expected drop down now. However, it would help, if you can share the full html for the page. So that, if you still face the same issue even after using the modified xpath, we can further troubleshoot it.

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to use Selenium 3.0.2 with Firefox 45. This creates issues and thus I could not select the dropdown values. I will add this as an answer, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Great. No worries. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to use Selenium 3.0.2 with Firefox 45. This creates issues and thus I could not select the dropdown values.I downgraded to Selenium 2.5.x and the problem went away. The issue was not the select was in a table as I first thought. I hope this helps somebody else in the future.Please see also the following question: [Python, Firefox and Selenium 3: selecting value from dropdown does not work with Firefox 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423691/python-firefox-and-selenium-3-selecting-value-from-dropdown-does-not-work-with)