# Python, Firefox and Selenium 3: selecting value from dropdown does not work with Firefox 45

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to open a website and select a value from a dropdown. Unfortunately the below does not work and after extensive research I am about to give up:
Python 3.6.0
Selenium 3.0.2
Firefox 45.7.0 (can't update due to company regulations)

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#set profile for firefox
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\Rash\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\FirefoxProfileCopies\\u4gehg17.default.copy")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)   
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)  
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\Rash\\Desktop\\TestDownloadFolderSelenium")  #set directory for download
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'application/vnd.ms-excel')

#start a browser session
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

# open the ProCon page
browser.get("http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?getstop=1&dbkanal_008=L01_S01_D001_KLR0011_konzernportal_LZ03")

select1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("REQ0HafasChangeTime"))
select1.select_by_visible_text("mindestens 30 Minuten")

for row in select1.options:
    print(row.text)
```

The weird thing is that the loop prints all the correct values from the correct dropdown menu but the `select`code does not work to change the dropdown to the value "mindestens 30 Minuten". The same problem occurs on different websites as well. Is this maybe a problem due to an older version of firefox?

I tried at home with Firefox 51.0.1 and it worked! It selected the right values. So I now wonder, since I can not update my Firefox at work, what can I do? Do I need to downgrade Selenium or geckodriver?

Comment: As far as I know Geckodriver is not fully compatible with Firefox 45. So your safest bet would be to downgrade Selenium to 2.53.1.

Comment: I just did, this solved my issue. I am just wondering whether I understand correctly: Selenium 2.53 does not use Geckodriver but Selenium 3.x does? Also please add this as an answer so I can accept. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Geckodriver is not fully compatible with Firefox 45. So your safest bet would be to downgrade Selenium to 2.53.1.

To answer your question from the comment.
It's a bit complicated. Selenium 3 needs Geckodriver to communicate with Firefox, which in turn is only fully compatible with Firefox 47 or later (unfortunately I didn't find a full compatibility list).
If you want (or have) to use Firefox 45 you cannot use a Selenium version that needs Geckodriver to work with Firefox.
So FF45 == no Geckodriver == any Selenium version below 3.

[This post](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3) might give you more information.